# How to map child parent on a single table using self Join in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, self-join

I have the following table with child parent relationship.

| ID | Title | PageID | IsParent | ParentID | IsActive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dashboard | 2125 | True | NULL | True |
| 2 | Site Analytics | 22 | False | NULL | True |
| 3 | SEO Management | 1 | NULL | NULL | True |
| 4 | Mail Management | 32 | NULL | NULL | True |
| 5 | Build Mobile App | 3214 | NULL | NULL | True |
| 6 | Market Analytics | 1321 | NULL | NULL | True |
| 7 | Customize | 235345 | NULL | NULL | True |
| 8 | Reporter | 253 | NULL | NULL | True |
| 9 | Editor | 545 | NULL | NULL | True |
| 10 | News Template | 45 | NULL | NULL | True |
| 11 | Test Menu | 0 | True | 3 | True |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Here `ParentID` defines the relationship between parent and child. For example, in the above table **Test Menu** is the child of `Site Analytics`. And I have the following SQL Query.

```
SELECT
        P.ID
        ,P.Title AS Parent
        ,C.Title AS Child
        ,P.PageID
        ,P.IsParent
        ,P.ParentID
        ,P.IsActive
      FROM [dbo].[ChildParent] P
      LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ChildParent] C ON P.ID = C.ParentID
```

Which results following output.

```
1   Dashboard           NULL            2125    1       NULL    1
2   Site Analytics      NULL            22      0       NULL    1
3   SEO Management      Test Menu       1       NULL    NULL    1
4   Mail Management     NULL            32      NULL    NULL    1
5   Build Mobile App    NULL            3214    NULL    NULL    1
6   Market Analytics    NULL            1321    NULL    NULL    1
7   Customize           NULL            235345  NULL    NULL    1
8   Reporter            NULL            253     NULL    NULL    1
9   Editor              NULL            545     NULL    NULL    1
10  News Template       NULL            45      NULL    NULL    1
11  Test Menu           NULL            0       1       3       1
```

Basically, what I want to achieve is :

```
1   Dashboard           NULL            2125    1       NULL    1
2   Site Analytics      NULL            22      0       NULL    1
3   SEO Management      NULL            1       NULL    NULL    1
4   Mail Management     NULL            32      NULL    NULL    1
5   Build Mobile App    NULL            3214    NULL    NULL    1
6   Market Analytics    NULL            1321    NULL    NULL    1
7   Customize           NULL            235345  NULL    NULL    1
8   Reporter            NULL            253     NULL    NULL    1
9   Editor              NULL            545     NULL    NULL    1
10  News Template       NULL            45      NULL    NULL    1
11  Test Menu           SEO Management  0       1       3       1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it backward.

```
  FROM [dbo].[ChildParent] P
  LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ChildParent] C ON P.ParentID = C.ID
```

Comment: minor detail here but if you have a WHERE clause filtering down on the Parent and the Child is not included this JOIN won't work.  The conditional needs to be formed the other direction P.ID = C.ParentID

Answer (score 3):

Try this little change in your query:

```
SELECT
        P.ID
        ,P.Title AS Parent
        ,C.Title AS Child
        ,P.PageID
        ,P.IsParent
        ,P.ParentID
        ,P.IsActive
      FROM [dbo].[ChildParent] P
      LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ChildParent] C ON isnull(P.ParentID, P.ID)  = c.id and C.ParentID is not null
```

Comment: @KiranShahi : can you provide more details? How different results is it giving?

Comment: This return all child column NULL

Comment: @KiranShahi  It should not.  Based on data you have provided in question, It should show one row from child which is 'SEO Management'.